# Implement IEnumerable<T> For a List Wrapper

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I have a class, which is just a wrapper over a list, i.e.,

```
public class Wrapper
{
   public List<int> TList
   {get;set;}
   public Wrapper()
   {
      TList=new List<int>();
   }
}
```

I want to make `Wrapper` inherits from IEnumerable so that I can use the following syntax:

```
Wrapper wrapper = new Wrapper()
                       {
                         2,4,3,6 
                       };
```

Any idea how to which interface to implement `IEnumerable<T>`, or `IEnumerable`, and how to define the method body?

Comment: No, with IEnumerable<T> it won't work. I think you have to implement ICollection<T>.

Comment: No, deerchao, it needs IEnumerable<T>. We do not *require* ICollection<T>, though of course, it is sensible to do so.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you implement [`ICollection<int>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13.aspx) you get the desired functionality.

Correction: you actually only need to implement `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<T>` and have a public `Add` method in your class:

```
public class Wrapper : IEnumerable<int>
{
    public List<int> TList
    { get; private set; }
    public Wrapper()
    {
        TList = new List<int>();
    }

    public void Add(int item)
    {
        TList.Add(item);
    }
    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return TList.GetEnumerator();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

(I also took the liberty of making the `TList` setter private; it is usually recommended that collection type properties are read-only so that the collection as such can not be substituted by any code outside the type.)

Comment: Why do we need to implement both a generic and a non-generic version of GetEnumerator?

Comment: @hdgarrood This is necessary because `IEnumerable<T>` inherits `IEnumerable` which is not generic. A type that implements `IEnumerable<T>` also implements `IEnumerable`, so those methods need to be present as well.

Comment: so can't I technically do `wrapperInstance.TList.Add()` and add an item without calling your Add wrapper or am I missing something?

Comment: @David There is no problem calling `wrapperInstance.TList.Add`. The `Wrapper.Add` method is necessary for the list initializer construct (`var x = new Wrapper { 1, 2, 3 }`) to work.

Answer (score 9):

In order to get collection initializers you need to do 2 things:

1. Implement IEnumerable
2. Have a method called Add with the correct signature

The preferable way to get these is to implement ICollection, but the minimum you need to do is:

```
public class Wrapper : IEnumerable<int>
{
    public List<int> TList
    {get;set;}

    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return TList.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() // Explicitly implement the non-generic version.
    {
        return TList.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void Add(int i)
    {
         TList.Add(i);
    }

    public Wrapper()
    {
        TList=new List<int>();
    }
}
```