# C# Collection class with generics

Tags: c#, .net, generics, collections

I want to lear how to create a collection class with generics in C#.
What i try to do is create a Class where i can add items to a List by using
generics

I already have some startup code

```
public class CollectionClass : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private List<T> list;
    /**
    * Method:   Add
    * @param    Object item to add
    */
    public void add(T item)
    {
        List.Add(item);
    }
}
```

But i cant make it work. Could somebody give me some advise or help.

Comment: You need to change `List.Add(item);` to `list.Add(item);` .

Comment: Your class must accept a generic type parameter like this: `public class CollectionClass<T> : IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: [Introduction to Generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x6a29h6.aspx) is good starting point... If you need copy-paste solution - searching for "implement IEnumerable" would give you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892768/implement-ienumerablet-for-a-list-wrapper

Answer (score 6):

Three things that you need in order for your code to compile:

1. You need to add a generic `T` parameter to your class

   ```
   public class CollectionClass<T> : IEnumerable<T>
   ```
2. You need to access `list` instead of `List`:

   ```
   public void Add(T item)
   {
      list.Add(item);
   }
   ```
3. Initialize your `list` variable (possibly via the constructor):

   ```
   public CollectionClass
   {
       list = new List<T>();
   }
   ```

Comment: Thx it works i was forgot to add the generic after CollectionClass.

Comment: There's another issue (I was posting an answer...). `list` is an unassigned reference.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer You're right, i missed that. Updated.