# DoublyLinkedList C# Removelast two elements

Tags: c#, list, linq

i tried to fix a code, which is a LinkedList. The task is to Remove the last X elements of the list.
I tried it with RemoveRange, but VS don't accept my solution and says, that RemoveRange doesn't exist.

```
var list = new DoublyLinkedList<string>();
list.Add("A");
list.Add("B");
list.Add("C");
list.Add("D");
list.Add("E");
list.RemoveLast(2);
```

This is the Code in the Program (Main).
In a second class there should be the method RemoveLast, but i dont get a working code. Can someone explain me, how i get the RemoveLast?

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Test
{
    public class DoublyLinkedList<T> : IEnumerable<T>
    {    
        public void RemoveLast(int v)
        {
            int remove = Math.Max(0, this.Count - v);

            this.RemoveRange(v, this.Count - v);              
        }
     }
}
```

RemoveRange is red underlined

Thank you for your help!

Full DoublyLinkedList:

```
`using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Test
{
    public class DoublyLinkedList<T> : IEnumerable<T>
    {
        public void RemoveLast(int v)
        {
            int remove = Math.Max(0, this.Count - v);

            this.RemoveRange(v, this.Count - v);



        }

        private sealed class Node
        {
            public T Item { get; set; }
            public Node Previous { get; set; }
            public Node Next { get; set; }
        }

        private Node first, last;

        public int Count { get; private set; }

        public void Add(T item)
        {
            Node newItem = new Node() { Item = item, Next = null, Previous = null };

            if (first == null)
            {
                first = newItem;
                last = newItem;
            }
            else
            {
                last.Next = newItem;
                newItem.Previous = last;

                last = newItem;
            }
            Count++;
        }

        IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
        {
            Node node = first;

            while (node != null)
            {
                yield return node.Item;
                node = node.Next;
            }
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return ((IEnumerable<T>)this).GetEnumerator();
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            string s = "";

            Node node = first;

            while (node != null)
            {
                s += node.Item.ToString() + " -> ";
                node = node.Next;
            }
            s += "Count: " + Count.ToString();

            return s;
        }

        private Node find(T item)
        {
            Node node = first;

            while (node != null)
            {
                if (node.Item.Equals(item))
                    return node;

                node = node.Next;
            }
            return null;
        }

        private Node findPrevious(T item)
        {
            Node previousNode = null;
            Node node = first;

            while (node != null)
            {
                if (node.Item.Equals(item))
                    return previousNode;

                previousNode = node;
                node = node.Next;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}`
```

Comment: which .net version are you using?

Comment: I use VS Community 2019, Version 16.5.4 @viveknuna

Comment: you can directly use `this.RemoveLast(v);`

Comment: Then I use the method in the method itself and i got a System.StackOverfloewException. I have to get the public void RemoveLast(int v) to work. But Like said in the question: i dont find the right way

Comment: you can inherit from `List<T>` then you can use the `RemoveRange()` method

Comment: I often read this before, but i dont know how i inherit it. 
In my second Class it's

```
public class DoublyLinkedList<T> : IEnumerable<T>
public void RemoveLast(int v)
{
int remove = Math.Max(0, this.Count - v);
this.RemoveRange(v, this.Count -v)
}```

But it doesn't work. VS doesn't know RemoveRange in this case. Using Directions are in.

Comment: @Unlexs check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892768/implement-ienumerablet-for-a-list-wrapper may be will help.

Comment: @Unlexs Could you share complete implementation of your `DoublyLinkedList`?

Comment: I checked this, Sajid, but i think i have implented all of this. And @IliarTurdushev i Did edit my question and filled in the complete DoublyLinkedList

Comment: And i don't understand, why i can't use the RemoveRange Method.

Comment: IEnumerable<T> doesn't have a RemoveRange() method. IEnumerable just exposes Enumeration functions. You want to Inherit from List<T> instead so you have access to List manipulation functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can implement `RemoveLast(int n)` in your `DoublyLinkedList`:

```
// Removes last "n" elements.
public void RemoveLast(int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        RemoveLast();
}

// Removes the last element.
public void RemoveLast()
{
    // List is empty. No need to remove elements.
    if (first == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    // List contains only one element. Remove it.
    else if (first == last)
    {
        first = null;
        last = null;
    }
    // List contains more than one element. Remove the last.
    else
    {
        // The next two lines make "last" to point to the element before the last.
        last = last.Previous;
        last.Next = null;
    }

    Count--;
}
```

Here is [complete sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uWfe2p).

Comment: Thank you very much for this help. This is exactly, what i've tried and don't got to work!
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You do know there is already a double linked list class, don't you?
[System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1?view=netcore-3.1)? My advice would be to use that class.

If it is too much work to redesign your code, for instance because your DoublyLinkedList is already used a lot, my advice would be to make DoublyLinkedList an adapter for LinkedList:

```
class DoublyLinkedList<T> : IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
{
    private readonly LinkedList<T> linkedList = new LinkedList<T>();

    public int Count => this.linkedList.Count;

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        this.LinkedList.Add(item);
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.LinkedList.GetEnumerator();
    }

    ... // etc.
}
```

You need to add a method to remove the last N items from your list. For example
RemoveLast(10) is supposed to remove the last 10 elements from your doubly linked list. If your list has 10 or less elements, this would clear your complete list.

```
void Clear()
{
    this.LinkedList.Clear();
}

void RemoveLast()
{
    if (this.LinkedList.Count != 0)
        this.linkedList.RemoveLast();
}

void RemoveLast(int removeCount)
{
    if (this.Count <= removeCount)
    {
        this.linkedList.Clear();
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i=0; i<removeCount; ++i)
        {
            this.RemoveLast();
        }
    }
}
```

It might be that your supervisor is stubborn and does not follow your advise to reuse fully tested trustworthy .NET classes. In that case you'll have to change the `RemoveLast()` method.

```
void Clear()
{
    this.first = null;
    this.last = null;
    this.count = 0;
}

void RemoveLast()
{
    switch (this.Count)
    {
        case 0:
            // empty list; do nothing
            break;
        case 1:
            // removing the last element of the list
            this.Clear();
            break;

       default:
           var lastNode = this.last;

           // because more than one element I'm certain there is a previous node
           var previousNode = lastNode.Previous;
           var previousNode.Next = null;
           this.last = previousNode;
           --this.count;
           break;
    }
}
```

Comment: In this case I'm not allowed to use the .net classes, but I got your point! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If `RemoveRange` is not available, you can easiliy roll your own implementation that works on any enumerable without Linq in this way (this code is an idea as I do not have access to all your code).

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

        public void RemoveRange(int count)
        {
            if (count > this.Count)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(count));

            while (count > 0)
            {
                RemoveTail();
                count--;
            }
        }

        private void RemoveTail()
        {
            if (this.Count == 0)
                return;

            var previous = last.Previous;
            if (previous != null)
            {
                previous.Next = null;
                last = previous;

                this.Count--;
            }
            else
            {
                // this implies count == 1
                last = null;
                first = null;

                this.Count = 0;
            }
        }
```

Essentially, you can expose your `RemoveRange` method and then perform an agnostic removal of the last node (tail) one by one.

This answer has been edited to reflect the code changes.

Comment: Thank you very much for your thoughts and the code, but this Code doesn't work on my code. Above i edited the rest of the doublylinkedlist. For example i don't implemented a RemoveAt. 

The only way is to use RemoveLast Methode. But i don't find the right way. Im into it like a week of searching in the web, try and fix the code, but till now i don't find the right way to delete the last x elements with the method.

Comment: It does not work because of some incorrect lines of mine. Let me fix it.

Comment: I posted the relevant part. Give it a try and let me know:)